# How to accept input from external keyboard on a webpage load using jquery

Tags: jquery, ios

I have a web page and, in this case a bluetooth RFID scanner that behaves like an external keyboard.

If I have a textbox on my web page, I can tap in it and scan and RFID tag and it behaves the same as if I'd typed the 20 digit (???) code into the box.

What I want to be able to do is, on Document Ready, either give focus to the textbox so that I can scan an RFID tag and have the value entered into the textbox....
OR
Be able to scan the tag and have it's value pushed into the textbox (or other HTML element, div, span, etc) automatically.

This is easy on a desktop, but I'm using an IOS device and nothing I have tried works..

I've tried binding the following events to "document" and "window":

- KeyUp
- KeyDown
- KeyPress
- Tap - jquery mobile

These options work fine on a pc, but as soon as it runs on an IOS device it just won't work as expected.

Does anyone have a solution for either setting focus automatically to a textbox on page load/document ready on IOS or some way of capturing keyboard input from a bluetooth external device or IOS in a webpage..

solution can be jquery or jquery mobile or even some other set of web based client tools..

Thanks

Comment: `$('#yourInput').focus()`

Comment: Thanks @Brad but it doesn't work from document ready on an ios device..  the textbox just doesn't get focus, that was the first thing we tried.